# Add a description of what the test does using parametrize of Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

It is possible to add a description in parametrize of what a test is testing for when one of them fails, know quickly why the test is failing.

Sometimes you don't know why a test fails (you have to look in the code). With a description for each test, you could know.

For example.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize( "num1, num2, expect", [
    (2, 2, 4), # This test verifies that 2+2 = 4.
])
def test_sum(num1, num2, expect):

    calc = Calc()
    response = calc.sum(num1, num2)
    assert expect == response
```

If the test failed, the error message would say:

```
src_test/calc.py::test_sum[19999997-200] FAILED
    assert vo_result.code == expected_code
E   AssertionError: assert 4 == 3
    **The test checks if the numbers add up well.** Message invented
```

Comment: Maybe it'd be better to just provide more informative message on assert, such as `assert vo_result.code == expected_code, f"This test verifies that {num1}+{num2} = {expect}."` or log this message in the beginning of he function

Comment: Thank you for answering @MikhailBerlinkov, I had thought about this option, to pass in the parametrize an attribute called ```test_name``` and add it to assert. I just wanted to know if there was any other way with Pytest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define id of each test in parameterization. Ids are appended to the test name. By default, the parameterization id is combination of parameters.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize( "num1, num2, expect", [
(2, 2, 4)], ids = ["2+2=4"])
def test_sum(num1, num2, expect):
    calc = Calc()
    response = calc.sum(num1, num2)
    assert expect == response
```

When the test runs, test name would be `test_sum[2+2=4]`.
When the test fails, you can look at test name and find which set of parameters caused the test to fail.

To fail individual tests, you can use pytest.params. e.g.:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize( "num1, num2, expect", [
                (2, 2, 4), pytest.param(2,3,9, marks=pytest.mark.xfail)], ids = ["2+2=4", "failing"])
def test_sum(num1, num2, expect):
    calc = Calc()
    response = calc.sum(num1, num2)
    assert expect == response
```

More about parametrization id from pytest reference doc: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-mark-parametrize

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this option. I don't know if it was thought for my purpose, but I find it interesting. Sometimes I want to put that if the parameter is so that it fails or so that the action of SUT is done correctly.

Comment: You can use `pytest.mark.xfail` for individual tests in param config. See parametrization docs (https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-parametrizing-test-functions).

Comment: Updated the answer for your use case.