# Pytest add a description to caller function without parametrize parameters

Tags: python, pytest

This question is quite similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662591/add-a-description-of-what-the-test-does-using-parametrize-of-pytest). However, I don't have any parameters to pass in (using parametrize decorator).

Take a look at how I use this test.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def driver(headless=True):
    opts = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    opts.add_argument('--headless') if headless else None
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)
    driver.get('http://localhost:8080/request')
    yield driver
    driver.quit()

#@pytest.mark.parametrize(ids="test the title of web page, further info: blah blah..")
def test_title(driver):
    """
    title of request page
    """
    driver.get('http://localhost:8080/request')
    assert driver.title == 'abc', "failed for: test title of web page'"
```

The commented parametrize decorator fails because there are non-optional parameters. Is there a way to add this simple description to the test and show it when it fails.

Comment: If the test fails, the whole test function is shown anyway, including the doc string - wouldn't it be sufficient to adapt the doc string accordingly? Or do you want to have the description in some specific place in the output?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I need some extra info to go with it when it fails. But this is sorta optional because I can indeed use the docstring. Although I want a little bit more flexibility because I intend to seperate these messages and import them accordingly.